# using c++ libraries in eclipse c++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse

As a newbie who doesn't know much about c++ libraries and project build/link procedure, let me ask the following:

1- What is the difference between

**Project -> Properties -> GCC C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes**

and

**Project -> Properties -> GCC C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes**

2- When should I use which one for external libraries in my project?
3- I see that libraries come with an include folder with a bunch of header files in it. Some libraries need compilation vs others don't. What's the difference? Why?
4- In what case do i need to deal with the following 
**Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries**
because i see sometimes people specify this Libraies(-l) thing and sometimes don't but i have no idea when it is supposed to be specified and when not.